# Как выводить элементы ListView в обратной последовательности?

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть `ListView`. При добавлении нового элемента он добавляется в конец списка. Логично, ведь это у нас `ListView`. Можно ли сломать систему, чтобы новые элементы добавлялись в начало списка. То есть, первый внесенный элемент будет в самом низу, а тот пункт, который мы добавили последним - будет вверху.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашей разметке, у элемента ListView установите 2 параметра

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```